What is killing my trees? (Northern Utah)
Our cherry tree is completely dead, our flowering parking strip tree is very nearly dead, and our apple tree seems to be well on its way.  What on earth is happening here?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A gas leak nearby?

Why is so much bark stripped off the trees in the pictures?   (That is probably at minimum a contributing factor - and unfortunately can't really be fixed)

As it stands this is asking for opinions. Are there other cherry trees around the are that are not dead? Select a 2inch diameter branch and cut it off, close to the trunk, is it totally dry?
